How to align variable declarations in columnar layout in IntelliJ IDEA (similar to Eclipse formatter)?
I've been working with Eclipse and have a code formatting rule set up that aligns my variable declarations in a columnar layout like this:
public static final String SORT_ORDER       = "sortOrder";
public static final String GROUPS           = "groups";
public static final String CUSTOMERS        = "customers";

However, when I import the same formatter into IntelliJ IDEA, it doesn't preserve this alignment and instead formats the code like this:
public static final String SORT_ORDER = "sortOrder";
public static final String GROUPS = "groups";
public static final String CUSTOMERS = "customers";

I've tried adjusting various settings in IntelliJ IDEA, but haven't found the right configuration to achieve the same columnar alignment as in Eclipse.
What are the correct settings or steps in IntelliJ IDEA to achieve this columnar layout for variable declarations, similar to how Eclipse handles it?

Do you mean the setting Editor > Code Style > Java Wrapping and Braces > Group declarations > Align fields in columns? As an aside, Eclipse and IntelliJ are different products, you cannot expect settings of one to map one-on-one to the other.
